# PHP : How to extract value of multidimensionnal array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this multidimensional array and I would like to get from it only `array('13', '11', '12', '10')`. How can I get this?

```
array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => '13' 
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => '11'
      2 => 
        array
          'id' => '12'
      3 => 
        array
          'id' => '10'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$values = array();
foreach($arr as $inner)
{
    $values[] = $inner['id'];
}
// $values should now hold array(13, 11, 12, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 for($i =0 ;$i<count($array);$i++)
 {
     echo $array[$i]['id'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$array  = your array

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
   $array=Array('0'=>Array('id'=>"1"),'1'=>Array('id'=>"2"),'2'=>Array('id'=>"3"),'4'=>Array('id'=>"4"));

   $arr=Array();
   for($i =0 ;$i<3;$i++)
   {
       $arr[$i]=$array[$i]['id'];
   }

   print_r(implode(',',$arr));
?>
```

O/p:

```
   1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $values = array();        
    foreach(new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($arr)) as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'id') $values[] = $value;
    }
    var_dump($values);
```